# How do you connect two buttons to one spinner in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

In my app I have one spinner. Depending on which option within the spinner is chosen, clicking the first button will show a result. I want my second button to take the user to a new "empty activity page" where they can click on a link to a webpage based off of the same results chosen in the spinner. Right now I have the first button working to show the first set of results, but I cannot connect my second button to also match with the spinner. I have created a second java file and a second receiveActivity java file. The private "BasicSites" class is not recognized in my code:

```
private BasicSites myBasicSite = new BasicSites();
public void getResults(View view) {

    Spinner brandSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String brandValue = String.valueOf(brandSpinner.getSelectedItem());
    myBasicSites.setBasicSites(brandValue);
    String suggestedBasicSites = myBasicSite.getBasicSites();
    String suggestedBasicSitesURL = myBasicSite.getBasicSitesURL();
    System.out.println(suggestedBasicSites);
    System.out.println(suggestedBasicSitesURL);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecieveBasicActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra("basicSitesName", suggestedBasicSites);
    intent.putExtra("basicSitesURL", suggestedBasicSitesURL);

    startActivity(intent);

    TextView basic_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.basicResult);

    EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_editText);
    String nameValue = name.getText().toString();
```